# How to print the content of a macro to the terminal

Tags: macros, terminal-output

I am writing letters of application to various companies and to speed up the process I have few macros defined in my `.tex` file i.e.

```
\def\company{ Company name ABCDEF }
```

I know that one can do

```
\typeout{\company}
```

and this will echo the macro to the `.log` file and to the console output, but somehow this didn't produce any output to the terminal.

For "compiling" the `.tex` file I use `pdflatex`

Since it is much easier I would like to see the output in my compile console. I usually use kile (linux) and TeXnicCenter (windows). Both of them produce output on the screen and it would be very helpful to see the content of the macros. It would be even greater if those messages are in red color.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you try `\show\mymacroname`?

Comment: What does `not work` mean? Is your `\def\...` in a group and are you trying to access `\typeout{\company}` outside of the group?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: The backdraw of `\show` is that it stops the compilation

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am not getting any output to the terminal.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: yes indeed.  It’s not very clear what the question is asking for, actually.

Comment: @AlexanderCska: If I compile directly on console (I always do so ;-)) I see `Company name ABCDEF`. Perhaps you should change to `\gdef` instead of `\def`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\gdef` didn't produce any output either.

Comment: @AlexanderCska: Try Gustavo's suggestion with `\show\company` then

Comment: @ChristianHupfer well this quite the same to what I gave as an example in my question. I need the output to the *.log screen.

Comment: @AlexanderCska: You asked about `output` to the `console`, not about `.log`!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer well in Kile the output is shown log window. It is the place where all errors and warnings are shown. I am talking about the log screen not the log file.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}



\gdef\company{ Company name ABCDEF } 

\begin{document}
\typeout{\company}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Danke Christian. I just tried your example in Kile and I didn't get the output. Only executing `pdflatex inp.txt` on the Linux terminal would do this, but I would like to use the text editor fro compiling. It is much neater.

Comment: @AlexanderCska: I've never needed such an 'editor' for almost 20 years and I have done some theses and papers and my everydays work with an ordinary editor like 'emacs'. Most likely `Kile` has a weird setting that prevents this

Comment: @AlexanderCska: The output is only seen in the terminal or logfile, not in the pdf!

Comment: @Herbert: Isn't the console output already clear from the question?

Comment: Well I also program in vi etc. but find it easier to use. Actually I used to generate such messages, but this was quite some time ago.

Comment: @AlexanderCska Above the lower window of Kile there are  a "Ouput" button that  show exactly the same messages that the terminal. When you are in "Log and Messages" there are also at the right a  "View log file"  icon that show also the `\typeout` messages.

Comment: @Fran I figured that out, is it possible to echo anything to the log window?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\gdef\company{ Company name ABCDEF } 
\begin{document}

    \show\company

    \typeout{Makroinhalt: \company}

\end{document}
```

Then run the document with `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode <file>` and
you'll get on the terminal:

```
voss@shania:~> pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode zz
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./zz.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./zz.aux)
> \company=macro:
-> Company name ABCDEF .
l.5     \show\company

Makroinhalt:  Company name ABCDEF 
(./zz.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
No pages of output.
Transcript written on zz.log.
```

Comment: There is a method to do the same with Kile

Comment: you can run the document in terminal mode and, of  course, all GUIs have already `-interaction=nonstopmode` set, otherwise it is not possible to handle the compilations. However, run the document from within kile and then view the logfile.

Comment: Some time ago I found here a method to produce on purpose warning messages on the terminal. Unfortunately, I can't find the thread now.